# Limit the max number of cart items in $_SESSION

Tags: php

This is my php script for adding item to shopping cart:

```html
session_start();
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();

switch($_GET['action']) {
case 'add':
$productByCode = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT item, brand, price, catalog FROM products WHERE catalog='".$_GET['catalog']."'");
$itemArray = array($productByCode[0][‘catalog']=>array(
  'item'=>$productByCode[0]['item'], 
  'brand'=>$productByCode[0]['brand'],
  'price'=>$productByCode[0]['price'],
  'catalog'=>$productByCode[0]['catalog']));

if(!empty($_SESSION['cart_item'])) {
if(!in_array($productByCode[0]['catalog'],($_SESSION['cart_item']))) {
$_SESSION['cart_item'] += $itemArray;
}
} 
else {
$_SESSION['cart_item'] = $itemArray;
}
```

I want to limit the max number of cart item to 20, that means when the cart items has reach 20, even if the user click the add button with new item not found in the $_session, the new item will not be added anymore. Is there any way to do this? Pls help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, please stop messing around with anything that is even remotely related to any shopping functionality, as long as you have not learned what to do against SQL injection ...

Comment: Secondly, what exactly do you mean - 20 different items in varying quantities (the latter being irrelevant), or a total of 20 when the ordered quantities are added up?

Comment: 20 different items in varying quantities, cool man, I am just learning here. .even that  script I copy from people's tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues. in_array won't work the way you have it because it compared the array value not the key. So use array_keys to test for that. You could also use `isset($_SESSION['cart_item'][$productByCode[0]['catalog'])` instead of in_array(array_keys(...)) to get the same effect.

I updated the add code to use array_merge so it is clear what is happening with the new cart items.

Also you should parameterize your sql query to avoid SQL injection issues (I didn't correct this in your code)

```html
session_start();
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();

switch($_GET['action']) {
case 'add':
$productByCode = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT item, brand, price, catalog FROM products WHERE catalog='".$_GET['catalog']."'");
$itemArray = array($productByCode[0][‘catalog']=>array(
  'item'=>$productByCode[0]['item'], 
  'brand'=>$productByCode[0]['brand'],
  'price'=>$productByCode[0]['price'],
  'catalog'=>$productByCode[0]['catalog']));

if(!empty($_SESSION['cart_item'])) {
   if(count($_SESSION['cart_item']) < 20 && !in_array($productByCode[0]['catalog'],array_keys($_SESSION['cart_item']))) {
      $_SESSION['cart_item'] = array_merge($_SESSION['cart_item'],  $itemArray);
   }
} 
else {
   $_SESSION['cart_item'] = $itemArray;
}
```

Comment: count($_SESSION['cart_item']) < 20  works as what I want. Thanks for the idea.